# Use of uninitialized value in print at jQuery/File/Upload.pm line 680

Tags: perl, cgi, jquery-file-upload

I am getting `Use of uninitialized value in print at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/jQuery/File/Upload.pm line 680.` error in apache logs. I am using jquery::File::Upload perl module.

My Cgi code is as follows:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use jQuery::File::Upload;

  my $j_fu = jQuery::File::Upload->new;
  $j_fu->upload_dir('/tmp/manish');
  $j_fu->handle_request;
  $j_fu->print_response;
```

line no 680 is:-

```
 print $self->output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it resolved by changing my request type from get to post because in perl module genrate_output method was being called from pre_post method instead of pre_get.